# How do you print matching strings across 2 lists using Python?

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists like so:

```
list1 = ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
list2 = ['Oranges', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries', 'Apples']
```

'Apples' and 'Oranges' are in both lists - is there a function in python that will enable me to print the matching strings in both lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `set.intersection`.

```
>>> list(set(list1).intersection(list2))
['Oranges', 'Apples']

>>> set(list1).intersection(list2)
{'Apples', 'Oranges'}
```

Comment: or set(list1) & set(list2)

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension:

```py
list1 = ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
list2 = ['Oranges', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries', 'Apples']
[item for item in list1 if item in list2]
```

Output:

```
['Apples', 'Oranges']
```